# Вопрос по сортировке в EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Проблема с этим запросом.

```
db.Table.Select(x => new { id = x.id, date = x.date }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.date).Select(x=>x.id).Distinct().Take(40);
```

При Вызове Distinct() все ключи теряют сортировку.
Такая же ситуация при вызове GroupBy(x=>x);

Помогите пожалуйста получить первые ключи без потери сортировки. Запрос должен быть выполнен на стороне SQL сервера, т.е. ни AsEnumerable(), ни ToList() после OrderByDescending не подходят.

И спрошу еще по теме:

```
db.Table.GroupBy(x=>x.id).Select(x=>x.First());
```

Какой аналог запроса для EF Core для серверной стороны существует ныне?

Comment: А нельзя использовать дополнительный `.OrderBy()` вот так: `.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).Take(40)`?

Comment: Мне нужно отсортировать по времени.  А так  получится по id/

Comment: В первом запросе `x.Key` - это опечатка? Должно быть `x.id`?

Comment: Да. Сори. Исправил.

Comment: Кто гарантирует, что значение `x.id` из `Select(x=>x.id)` соответствует какому-то определенному `x.date`? Никто.

Comment: Мне просто нужно получить отсортированные по дате и уникальные id. Можно и без Select(x=>x.id), можно и в комплекте с data. Distinct() все перемешивает.

Comment: Вы, по-моему, не поняли, что я написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db.Table.GroupBy в EFCore3.1 не работает! Сам недавно долбился с этой проблемой. Может быть в EFCore5 и вернули, но не могу утверждать.

Что касается вашего проблемного запроса:

```
var qr = db.Table.Select(x => new { id = x.id, date = x.date })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.date).Select(x => x.id).Distinct().Take(40);
var result = db.Table.Where(w => qr.Contains(w.id))
    .Select(x => new { id = x.id, date = x.date })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.date).Select(x => x.id)
    .ToList(); //если вам ToList() не нужен - он не обязателен
```

Как выглядит вывод qr и result соответственно на выборке из 5 результатов вместо 40 на моей БД (сортировка по времени сохраняется):

```
qr     result
12951  12952
12952  12953
12953  12955
12954  12951
12955  12954
```

Данный код выглядит как следующий SQL запрос:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM Table_ AS r
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT r0.id
        FROM Table_ AS r0
        LIMIT @__p_0
    ) AS t
    WHERE t.id = r.id)
ORDER BY r.date DESC
```

Comment: SQL запрос работает, а Linq вылетает с исключением по преобразованию.

Comment: Странно, но у меня linq работал на живой БД. А SQL - из лога выполнения linq.

Comment: Возможно, я что-то невнимательно сделал (мозги слипались), либо из-за того, что у меня EFcore 5.

Comment: В EFCore5 db.Table.GroupBy может работать, но это не отменяет того, что и этот код должен работать.